# Advanced T-SQL: How Should I Update Multiple Rows While Updating Multiple Columns?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for that performance 'sweet spot' when trying to update multiple columns for multiple rows...

Background.

I work in an MDM/abstract/hierarchical classification/functional SQL Server environment. This question pertains to a post data driven calculation process where I need to save the results. I pass JSON to a SQL function that will automatically create SQL for inserts/updates (and skip updates if the values match).

The tblDestination looks like

```
create table tblDestination as 
(
     sysPrimaryKey bigint identity(1,1)
     , sysHeaderId bigint  -- udt_ForeignKey
     , sysLevel1Id bigint -- udt_ForeignKey (classification level 1)
     , strText nvarchar(100) -- from here down: the values that need to be updated
     , dtmDate datetime2(7)
     , numNumeric flat
     , flgFlag bit
     , intInteger bigint
     , sysRefKey  bigint-- ForeignKey
     , primary key non clustered (sysPrimaryKey)
)
```

/* note that the clustered index on this table exists, contains more than the columns listed above, and is physically modeled correctly. you may use any clustered/IX/UI indexes that you need to if you are testing */

@JSON looks like... (ARBITRARY# ranges between 2 and 100)

```
declare @JSON nvarchar(max)='{"ARBITRARY NAME 1":"3/1/2017","ARBITRARY NAME 2": "Value", "ARBITRARY NAME 3": 45.3}'
```

The **function** cursors through the incoming @JSON and builds insert or update statements.

```
Cursor local static forward_only read_only
for
select [key] as JSON_Key, [value] from openjson(@json)

while @@fetch

-- get the id for ARBITRARY ID plus a classification id

select @level1Id = level1Id, @level2id = level2Id
from tblLevel1 where ProgrammingName = @JSON_Key

-- get a ProgrammingName field for the previously retrieved level2Id

Select @ProgrammingName =  /*INTEGER/FLAG/NUMERIC/TEXT/DATE/REFKEY
from tblLevel2 where level2id = @level2id 


-- clear variables

set @numeric = null, @integer = null, @text = null etc..

-- check to see if insert or update is required

Select @DestinationID from tblDestination where HeaderId = @header and Level1 = @Level1

if @DestinationId is null

begin

If @ProgrammingName = 'Numeric' begin @Numeric = @JSON_Value end

else if @ProgrammingName = 'Integer' begin @Integer = @JSON_value end

etc..

-- dynamically build the updates here..

    /*
    'update tblDestination
    Set numeric = ' +@numeric
    +', flag = '+@flag
    +', date = '+@date
    .. etc
    +'where HeaderId = '+@header + ' and level1Id = '+@Level1Id
    end

    IE:
    Update tblDestination
    Set numNumeric = NULL
    , flgFlag = NULL
    , dtmDate = '3/1/2017'
    Where sysPrimaryKey = 33676224
    */
```

**Finally**... to the point of this post: has anyone here had experience with multiple row updates on multiple columns?

Something like:

```
Set TableNumeric
= CASE WHEN Level3Id = 33676224 then null
when leve3id = 33676225 then 3.2
when level3id = 33676226 then null
end
, tableDate = case when level3id = 33676224 then '3/1/2017'
when 33676225 then null
when 33676226 then null 
end
where headerId = 23897
and IDs in (33676224, 33676225, 33676226)
```

I know that the speed varies for Insert statements (Number of Columns inserted vs Number of records), and have that part dialed in.

I am curious to know if anyone has found that 'sweet spot' for **updates**.
The sweet spot meaning:

How many CASES before I should make a new update block?

Is 'Update tbl set (Column = Case (When Id = ## then ColumnValue)^n END)^n' the proper approach to reduce the number of actual Updates being fired?

Is wrapping Updates in a transaction a **faster** option (and how many per COMMIT)?

Legibility of the update statement is irrelevant. Nobody will actually see the code.

I have isolated the single update statement chain to be approx 70%+ of the query cost in question (compared to all inserts and 20/80,50/50,80/20 %update/%inserts)

Comment: which programming language you using to connect to database?

Comment: I spent time reading through your question, and there is a lot of extra unexplained information in it like what is `@header`, `@level1` variables. I suggest you clean up and rephrase so that the question actually receives good responses

Comment: Everything is SQL based.  middle tier is just for display (.net)
the calc is data driven. 

the question pertains to updating a 'matrix' and the fastest way to update blocks. (not single rows or single columns, but many and many)

headerid is the parent id of this table. Example: PartName has a headerId of PartId from the tblPart table.

Level1 is the most atomic classificationId for the current table. PartName level1Id might be Samsung Internal Name under level2 Samsung under level3 Business Names